# Pass data between methods in a class

Tags: swift

I'm having a hard time understanding this basic mechanism of swift. I'm able to find tutorials for how to pass data between view controllers, but not how to pass data between methods in a view controller.

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController{

 var array = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
array = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
print(array)
}
```

I try to explain what I'm attempting with this simplified example. First i declare an empty array which can be used within all methods of the class, so far so good. However, after giving the array an initial value in the viewdidload method, I'm not able to "keep" this data when using the same array in another method (in this example i want to use the array data to customize the cells in the collection view).

I've tried putting the viewvdidload method inside the scopes of the collectionview method and vice versa. I'm not able to advance learning swift without knowing how this works.

Comment: You need to use `var` when declaring your property so that it can be modified. `var array = [String]()`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson My bad, I'm using var in my code but it still doesen't work

Comment: What doesn’t work? Your code should print an array with 3 items now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reload Your Collection View after inserting values in array in viewDidLoad method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  array = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
  self.collectionView!.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: That one line was what I was missing, thanks! I'm now able to pass the data in the array variable from viewdidload into the collectionview method. Is this something you commonly do when passing data between methods in a class?

Comment: CollectionView Delegates methods are being called before you insert values in Array. So you need to reload collection view to call delegates methods again.

Comment: it would be easier to assign the values directly to your array so you don't need to reload data at viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Yes, You can do that also.

Comment: I think OP should learn how to inject this data from another view controller and if he needs to return any value from the table view he would need to learn how to create a delegate to his view controller

Comment: That is what I initially tried, but after creating a database reference from firebase `var db: DatabaseReference!` I vas not able to access the db refernce variable outside the scope of a function, which is why I did it this hard way.